# How to animate the width and height of a <View /> in React Native?

Tags: react-native, animation, expo

So this works for me:

```
<Animated.View
  style={{
    ...styles.animatedBox,
     width: animWidth
  }}
>
  // some content...
<Animated.View>

Animated.spring(animWidth, {
  toValue: 400,
  speed: 10,
  bounciness: 5,
}).start();
```

But I want to use the `useNativeDriver: true` option which doesn't support width and height properties. Is there a way to still animate width/height changes? Can `translateX` and `translateY` be used for this somehow?

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated

You can get almost any animation with this. Even you can make animations with pure JS but this library makes it all for you.

Also, some animation docs:
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/next/animations